# iOS7: How does Apple make a navigation controller look like a uiactionsheet in the calendar app

Tags: ipad, cocoa-touch, ios7

On an iPad, in the calendar app, clicking on the "+" button in the upper right corner presents a view that is imposed on top of the current view like a UIActionSheet spawning from a UIBarButtonItem. However, this view clearly contains a UINavigationController, something that the UIActionSheet cannot do natively.

I'm hoping that Apple has exposed the ability to do this so that I don't have to reproduce it on my own. Can someone provide some insight on how I might approach this concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you this is not a `UIActionSheet` but a `UIPopoverController`, which can embed a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: You know, I've been writing iOS code for 3 years now, and I've never used a `UIPopoverController`. I think you are correct.