# How to display datepicker like that in iOS 7 calendar UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, calendar, uidatepicker, uiactionsheet

I'm new to iOS development, learning bits and pieces.
I've few more queries in continuation to another thread ([iOS7: How does Apple make a navigation controller look like a uiactionsheet in the calendar app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405871/ios7-how-does-apple-make-a-navigation-controller-look-like-a-uiactionsheet-in-t)) on iOS 7 new event creation in default calendar that's shown when we click + on UINavigationBar (I assume).

Does anyone know how to create UIDatePicker so that its displayed/hidden when I click on Start/End date field? I saw one video where UIActionSheet was used in XCode 4.5, but in that user needs to click on Done etc button to hide it. In iOS 7 calendar its hidden when I click outside picker i.e. on Start Date field. I hope question is clear?

Kindly advise how to achieve this feature?

Comment: The calendar app uses a `UITableViewController`. When the user taps on the start or end date, it adds a new `UITableViewCell` containing the `UIDatePicker`. While displaying the date picker, if any other cell in the table is selected, the cell containing the date picker is removed from the table. If you carefully tap on a gray area (i.e., not on a cell), you'll notice the date picker is not removed.

Comment: Thank you very much @bobnoble, that makes sense. Pardon my lack of knowledge, as I mentioned I'm still learning. so asking more here

I want the UI screen nearly same to the one shown on iOS 7's default calendar that I described above. So I assume, I'll add UITableViewCells in UITableViewController's table view on my storeyboard and put in required fields, is that correct ? or I need to add these programmatically?

If I add at design time - how will ReusableIdentifier work? so far I was populating UITableview with data from sqlite and set this identifier to one value i.e. "Cell".

Comment: You can create multiple prototype `UITableViewCell`s using storyboard, each with a unique identifier.

Comment: absolutely brilliant @bobnoble :-), thank you for guiding.

Comment: There is one sample source code provided by Apple, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008866 just found out.

seems many people have asked for this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973573/ios7-how-to-display-a-date-picker-in-place-in-a-table-view

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use the **[OCCalendarController](https://github.com/ocrickard/OCCalendar)**, Its so simple and comfortable. Just download the zipped file and get all the files named after the prefix **OC**.

Of which in **OCCalendarViewController.m** you can make the necessary changes by adding Okay or Cancel buttons programmatically, yourself.

To call the calendar view in your main file use the lines,

`//Here's where the magic happens 
calVC = [[OCCalendarViewController alloc] initAtPoint:CGPointMake(150, 50) inView:self.view]; calVC.delegate = self; [self.view addSubview:calVC.view];`

Also do include the following delegate to receive the date selection(if the user selects a date or date range)

`- (void)completedWithStartDate:(NSDate *)startDate endDate:(NSDate *)endDate {`

Finally you can also customize the arrow(which appears along with the calendar view) by using the code,

`[OCCalendarViewController alloc] initAtPoint:insertPoint inView:self.view arrowPosition:OCArrowPositionRight]`

Rest of the details can be found on the read me file. Try out yourself, It'll work like a charm.Cheers!

Comment: This code is old and unsupported. You're probably better off looking elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

My open source project HSUDatePicker may help you.
https://github.com/tuoxie007/HSUDatePicker